# Rails: get parent records having ZERO has_many associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's my associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Pretty straightforward. I want a scope on the `User` model which returns all users having exactly ZERO associated tickets.

Presently I'm using Ruby to do it for the most part like so:

```
def self.never_flown
  results = []
  find_each do |user|
    results << user if user.tickets.count == 0
  end
  results
end
```

... which sucks because this isn't a good use-case for Ruby. But I'm struggling to figure out how to do this using SQL.

Can someone let me know a good, clean SQL solution to this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like: `User.includes(:tickets).where(tickets: {user_id: nil})`

in a scope it would be like `:without_tickets, -> { includes(:tickets).where(tickets: {user_id: nil}) }`

Answer (score 1):

A SQL subquery could be used, which might be more efficient than using `includes()`:

```
User.where('id not in (select user_id from tickets)')
```

Comment: This works as well, but I'm selecting the above answer as it's arguably more clear. I want to benchmark both, however, and confirm which performs better.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders.user_id = users.id WHERE orders.user_id IS NULL")
```

Although @oliver-roset's approach is a bit simpler and easier to understand for anyone reading your code later.